# No hostile mobs spawning in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm absolutely sure I am not in peaceful mode I'll even provide my server properties at the end of this. I've tried switching between hard mode to peaceful and back again, nothing works. I've waited a few night, with no torches and far away from spawn points, no mobs spawn, not even in the caves. This is not a bukkit server and there are no mods or plugins. This has been happening since the recent 1.7.2 update and it's only in multiplayer server. If I play a in single player they'll spawn but if I transfer the world over to multiplayer all the mobs disappear. I can spawn mobs with a spawn egg but once you kill them they're gone. I've tried several different solutions from different forums but nothing helps.

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Wed Nov 20 10:50:50 PST 2013
generator-settings=
op-permission-level=4
allow-nether=true
level-name=world
enable-query=false
allow-flight=false
announce-player-achievements=true
server-port=25565
level-type=DEFAULT
enable-rcon=false
force-gamemode=false
level-seed=
server-ip=
max-build-height=256
spawn-npcs=true
white-list=false
spawn-animals=true
snooper-enabled=true
hardcore=false
online-mode=true
resource-pack=
pvp=true
difficulty=1
enable-command-block=false
player-idle-timeout=0
gamemode=0
max-players=5
spawn-monsters=true 
view-distance=10
generate-structures=true
spawn-protection=1
motd=A Minecraft Server
```

Comment: difficulty=1

Could this be your problem?  I'm not very familiar with servers, so I'm not sure if "peaceful" would be 0 or 1.

Comment: Difficulty of 0 is peaceful, and is not causing this issue.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. It might be that the server is spawning too many friendly mobs to fit in any hostile ones.

Comment: I do not think the can be to many non-hostile mobs, or im pretty sure.

Comment: @Kazeuchi What have you learned about this?  Were you able to solve?  I'm seeing identical behavior in single player mode.

Comment: @John - I'm also seeing identical behaviour in single player mode. Any solutions?

Comment: @Tama this question addresses single player mode issues in 1.7.4  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147958/1-7-4-problem-with-mobs-spawning

Answer (score 6):

What i would suggest is downloading the server package again, and copying the new properties file into the folder where your Minecraft server is located. If you have edited anything in the file (which it seems you have) try running it stock settings and see if that works.

Then, change settings one at a time to ensure that you can see what setting is causing the issue.

I've run a Minecraft server on Windows and Linux, and never encountered this problem, but  hopefully this solves yours.

Answer (score 1):

This seems weird. Difficulty=1 is Easy. Loads of mobs are ment to spawn in Easy, some are ment to spawn in Normal and not many spawn in hard (except they are easier to beat.) Except that has nothing to do with your question.

Here are things I suggest you should do:

- Download the server file again from [Minecraft.net](http://minecraft.net) and try again.
- It might be a server error, and it might be a bug that Mojang has created. Report it at something like MCBugs.

EDIT: Access the MCBUG site [here](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC)

Comment: This is false. Difficulty does not affect spawn rates in any way, except for Peaceful, which disables hostile mobs entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Wed Nov 20 10:50:50 PST 2013
generator-settings=
op-permission-level=4
allow-nether=true
level-name=world
enable-query=false
allow-flight=false
announce-player-achievements=true
server-port=25565
level-type=DEFAULT
enable-rcon=false
force-gamemode=false
level-seed=
server-ip=
max-build-height=256
spawn-npcs=true
white-list=false
spawn-animals=true
snooper-enabled=true
hardcore=false
online-mode=true
resource-pack=
pvp=true
difficulty=2
enable-command-block=false
player-idle-timeout=0
gamemode=0
max-players=5
spawn-monsters=true 
view-distance=10
generate-structures=true
spawn-protection=1
motd=A Minecraft Server
```

Comment: Why should they try this configuration? What it is supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends. If you have multiple accounts, check if you have a Minecraft running on the second account. If you do, then x it out. If you have two Minecrafts running on two accounts, and you are on a server, even if you have it to where it spawns mobs, then it will not spawn them.