# 1.7.4 Problem with mobs spawning

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have just updated to Minecraft 1.7.4 and now all of a sudden there are barely any mobs spawning.  I checked to make sure that I was in normal difficult and I saw 1 creeper but that is all.  Also I tried different difficulties.
Another thing - mobs seem to to spawn normally in the nether and all other mobs except aggressive mobs spawn like they should.  Please if you know how to fix this, please help!

Comment: Check your render distance. If it is around 6, try something around 12. There was a glitch tied to render distance, though I cannot recall anything specific.

Comment: I cant use render distance above 6 my computer is not good enough would it help if I downgrade to minecraft 1.7.2 and would I lose any thing if I downgrade.

Comment: 1.7.2 is the same except for some bugfixes and Twitch. But try upping the view distance just to test, anyway. It may even fix the problem after you switch back, you'll have to try yourself...

Comment: I'd like to confirm that I am experiencing this bug as well.
I'm running it on windows with a render distance of 8.
Here is a link to the issue-tracker
https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-42053

Comment: I have same problem on Minecraft 1.7.4, chaning rendering distance to 8 and higher solved this issue.

Comment: Is it a superflat world? sorry if this sounds stupid, but i read somewhere about updated mob spawning based on height or something like that.

Comment: Glitch, and solution confirmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found out was that this is glitch like mentioned in comments the render around 6 is about were it happens the best thing to do is to downgrade or to wait for the next update.