# No hostile mobs spawning

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Minecraft in Survival, and no hostile mobs are spawning! This has been happening for the past week or so. I also tried Creative mode (superflat) and mobs *are* spawning there.

**What would cause mobs to stop spawning in Survival?**

Details:

- Minecraft 1.7.2
- Using Rei's mini map mod
- Windows Vista
- Created a new super flat world (creative) and mobs spawn

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what you're trying to say here.  Are mobs not spawning?

Comment: are you in peaceful difficulty?

Comment: Did you accidentally set `/gamerule doMobSpawning false` somehow? I'd try a clean reinstall (backup your saves first) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I am not in peaceful

Comment: And yes, mobs are NOT spawning

Comment: I did not touch the "game rule commands" But I will try...       !thank you!

Comment: !IT WORKED! thank you sooooooooooooo much (I wonder how it got to that, the ... "/gamerule doMobSpawning false")

Comment: @diana sharing the server with someone perhaps?  Or the single-player account if that's what you're doing?  Might be someone else changed it and it was left that way.

Comment: oh... That might be it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your render distance is set less than 8.  This is a known issue introduced in 1.7.2 when they allowed fine grain control over render distance.  Set render distance large (16?) and you'll have lots of mobs.

This question is a duplicate of [1.7.4 Problem with mobs spawning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147958/1-7-4-problem-with-mobs-spawning)