# Mobs Not Spawning In Minecraft Java 1.16.1 Creative Mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I play Minecraft Java 1.16.1 Creative Mode on TLauncher.

I recently made a single player offline new world in which I did not change any setting except changing to Large Biomes, cheats on and Creative Mode. I've been looking for some mobs to kill but they're not at all spawning anywhere.

I've tried making spawners, using spawn eggs, but they appear for a  split second then disappear.

I've also tried `/gamemode doMobSpawning true`

Please help as soon as possible.

Comment: Turn your game mode off “peaceful” to easy, medium, or hard.

Comment: Are you on Peaceful mode?

Comment: Yes, I'm on peaceful. Thank you so much. I'm sort of a beginner so I thought maybe peaceful mode would make the mobs peaceful 

Comment: Can you please answer this question? I'll mark it as closed.

Comment: @Akif_614 You can always post your own answer to your own question and mark it as the solution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about illegal software.

Comment: This "TLauncher" seems to be a real pest, I see it all the time here.

Comment: Actually looking over this, even tough this question mentions Tlauncher, it's of no relevance to this question. This should still be closed for another reason: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142795/no-hostile-mobs-spawning-in-minecraft?rq=1 is essentially a duplicate.  Also not everyone in the world is a copyright maximalist. Sometimes you need to disable drm even when you bought a game (see: [Darkspore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/darkspore)) to play it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on Peaceful mode.

If the player is on Peaceful mode or `spawn-monsters` is set to false in a server's server.properties file, hostile mobs won't spawn.

There are 2 outcomes for when 1 of the conditions mentioned above is met:

1. Not spawning at all
2. Despawning in a split second

The first outcome is for when you try to use **spawners**, in which hostile mobs won't spawn, no matter what lighting level you are on.

The second outcome is for when you try to use ways such as **commands** or **spawn eggs**, in which you'll see the mob spawn, but then despawn in a split second. This is more common than the other since spawners are rarely ever used for maps or are rarely ever encountered in survival, which in most cases the player or the server doesn't happen to be meeting any of the conditions above.